# .htaccess language switch with path

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-accept-language

I have the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(de|en)/(.*)$ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^de [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /de/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^$ /en/ [L,R=301]
```

domain.tld redirects to domain.tld/{lng}/

How to let domain.tld/news redirect to domain.tld/{lng}/news?

Comment: When you enter `domain.tld/de/news` in your browser does it open news page in `de` language? OR you get 404?

Answer (score 0):

For both English and German, add these rules (tested these rules on Apache 2.2 and 2.4):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^(en|de) [NC]
RewriteRule ^news/?$ %1/news [L]
```

Let me know if this works for you. :)